# Different ways to ask help from strangers

Tags: usage, expressions, word-usage

1) Offering help to strangers in Japanese is te form shimashouka ( o tetsudaishimashouka- Shall I help you / Do you need any help ?)

2) What are the different ways to seek help ( one I know is eki no juushou o oshite moraimasuka ? )

Comment: You usually say something like: すみません、駅を探してるんですが。and let the other person conclude that you what him to explain where to find it. So in general I would say, you just explain your problem.

Comment: This is slightly broad, did you have anything specific in mind?

Comment: As ajsmart indicates, it depends on what you want help with, from whom, and how much Japanese you know.  But in general, you can just say "sumimasen" and then ask your question directly and simply (e.g., eki wa doko desu ka).  (Asking for the address of a station sounds a bit strange for most purposes.)

Answer (score 1):

> Searching help to find the station

Speaking to people on the street, you usually say something like: (あのう、)すみません、駅を探してるんですが...((anou,) sumimasen, eki o sagashiterun ga...), look a bit help- and hopeless, and let the other person conclude that you want him to explain where to find it.

In real life people will often go out of their way to help you. So they might not just describe how to find it, but show you the way on a smart phone app, or even accompany you to a place from where you can see it.

So in general I would conclude, you just explain your problem.

Comment: Based on the OP's question, I'm not sure they can read Japanese so you might want to add romanji.